# Can't set element.style.float in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, css-float

I've posted the following javascript code as a <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gx8PS/1/)</kbd>.  It's pretty basic, and works fine in IE11 and in Chrome, but FireFox quietly throws away my `float` settings.  When I inspect the elements with FireBug, neither of them have `float` set in their style.

Why?

Surfing the web, I've gotten the vague impression that it has something to do with `width` needing to be set somewhere, but where?  And if that's the issue, is there a way for me to do this in firefox without knowing the width of the container?

```
var titleElem = document.createElement("div");
    titleElem.innerHTML = "Testing";
    titleElem.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
    titleElem.style.border = "0px transparent";
    titleElem.style.width = "auto";
    titleElem.style.float = "left";
    titleElem.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    titleElem.style.overflow = "hidden";
    titleElem.style.position = "relative";

document.body.appendChild(titleElem);

    rangeElem = document.createElement("div");
    rangeElem.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
    rangeElem.style.width = "auto";
    rangeElem.style.border = "0px transparent";
    rangeElem.style.float = "right";
    rangeElem.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    rangeElem.style.overflow = "hidden";
    rangeElem.style.position = "relative";
    rangeElem.style.fontSize = "x-small";
    rangeElem.style.paddingRight = "5px";
    rangeElem.className = "rangeDiv";
    rangeElem.innerHTML = "<i>[1234 - 5678]</i>";

document.body.appendChild(rangeElem);
```

Comment: Ha!  I just noticed in the code I posted - prettify obviously thinks that `float` is a keyword, as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing that line to

```
titleElem.style.setProperty('float', 'left')
```

Or,

```
rangeElem.style.cssFloat = 'left'
```

also works.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem right there.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gx8PS/3/)'s the updated fiddle, for anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 2):

You use `.cssFloat` to access that style property.

```
titleElem.style.cssFloat = "left";
```

Apparently, this has to do with `float` being a reserved word in javascript.